# How to get the cmap code of a CJK character in iText?

Tags: java, itext

We're developing a Java application to replace some fixed Chinese characters with a dynamic word in a PDF document, based on iText.

Now we can locate the fixed Chinese characters inside PDF, but we don't know how to replace them. The problem is we can not generate the cmap code of the dynamic Chinese word, if this word is in UTF-8 encoding.

Is there iText API or sample codes capable to handle this? Kindly please help us out, thanks so much!

Comment: As you don't show how your code works, it is hard to help you. But I suppose you are doing something wrong anyways, the code may depend on the specific font as defined for the given page, but you seem to think it is uniformly defined.

Comment: @mkl thanks for your hint, so could you please advise what's the decisive factors for the the cmap code? If the font type and size are always the same on different pages, with only the position changed. Will their cmap codes be the same?

Comment: *If the font type and size are always the same* - are you sure the PDF font object referred to also always are the same? The same font type can be used via different font objects which may have different encodings.

Comment: @mkl now we can define the same font type, font size and encoding (utf-8) across different pages. I'm not sure if this will uniquely define a cmap code of any Chinese character. Thanks a lot!